# Make href link clickable using J-Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using jquery menu and i want to make clickable when i click one of the links in the menu.  For instance, i want to open another asp.net page if i click the Report link, how can i do that?  here is my j-query menu:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $("#menu").menu();
      });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  .ui-menu { width: 150px; }
  </style>


 <ul id="menu">  
        <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
</ul>
```

so when i click the Report menu, i want to open this page Main_Report.aspx.  thanks

Comment: use button instead of a tag

Comment: `$('#menu li a').click(function(){//yourfunction here});`

Comment: @KuashalKhamar: ... said the actress to the bishop. Also, is a fiddle really required if the answer is to just use the `href` attribute as it was intended? :)

Comment: Methinks SO needs to dissuade people from asking for fiddle links.  They can be useful at the right time, but it's getting beyond a joke how often people ask for them

Comment: As a best practice, it is good include a Fiddle when asking questions.  Doesn't hurt, and it helps in many cases.  However, since moe did post the code (and since it is a straightforward question), I don't think it is that critical with this.

Comment: @LauraRitchey That's the point though.  Questions that don't post code should not remain open, unless it's a discussion type question.  It's getting really silly recently though, where someone could post _"How do I make this link blue? `<a href='#'>link</a>`"_ and the first comment will be someone asking for a jsfiddle.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please use below  code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#menu li a:contains(Report)").click(function () {
             if ($(this).attr("href") == "#") {
                 $(this).attr("href", "Main_Report.aspx");
             }
         });
     });
      </script>
       <style type="text/css">
      .ui-menu { width: 150px; }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <ul id="menu">  
            <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need of two js version you can use one version.

Comment: Basically I have old version of js file that what i have used it but you can use any js file for it.   1->min.js is for websites (online)

2->.js is for developers, guys who needs to read, learn about or/and understand jquery codes, for ie plugin development (offline, local work)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need jQuery to do that for you.  Simply put the url in the href attribute of the link...

```
<a href="Main_Report.aspx">Report</a>
```

If, for some unexplained reason, you *need* to do it with jQuery then just put this after you create the menu...

```
$("#menu").find("a:contains(Report)").attr("href", "Main_Report.aspx");
```

That will find the link tag that contains the word "Report" and set the href attribute to the report page.

***Note***: As per Flater's comment below, it really would be better to have a class or ID to reference the link with.  The way I suggested with `contains()` is not optimal, but will work.

Comment: But to be fair, it'd be way better, and easier, if you start using either classes or id's when looking things up via jQuery. Not saying your solution isn't valid, but I'd opt for suggesting a class/id based approach then :)

Comment: Yes, of course I agree that would be better.  Links are perfect for unique ID's, but in this case I'm just answering this immediate question as it is.

Comment: I know :) It was more meant as a tip for OP, rather than correcting you :) I could've phrased it differently, I guess.

Comment: I understand - I do the same myself.  You don't know how far to go sometimes though, short of rebuilding a website for someone :p

Comment: I have several of these reactions per day on SO: http://media.giphy.com/media/dZXOXsWBkoN3y/giphy.gif . I jest :) but still ;)

Comment: Lol - yes.  I know that feel :)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using anchor tag `<a>`, so you can make use of `href=''` attribute:

```
<ul id="menu">  
    <li><a href="Main_Report.aspx">Report</a></li>
</ul>
```

or if you want a js solution then try this:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var nUrl = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    window.location.href = nUrl + 'Main_Report.aspx';
});
```

Comment: `window.location.href = "main_report.aspx"` - you don't need any string manipulation to go to a relative address.

Answer (score 1):

As archer said you can simply navigate through anchor tag itself .. anyway this is my try
HTML

```
<ul id="menu">  
        <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu").find('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   window.location.href="youurl.html";
});
});
```